# Admin category menu in magento facing error

Tags: php, magento-1.7, categories

I have install theme and manage category and added product from admin side. There was not showing any error but today, admin side when I click on category menu, I found an error.
Can you please suggest me the solution .
Magento version : 1.7
PHP version : 5.3
[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Please provide me solution

Comment: This error is due to installation of your new theme. Please ask solution for that support team of that theme